# How to get YouTube JavaScript Player API with HTML5 to autostart on android

Tags: javascript, android, html, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

The following code executes correctly and auto plays and HTML5 youtube video on all OS's and browser versions  except on chrome in android. Is there a setting in android OS to modify or a work around to get this video to autoplay somehow?? There has to be way.

```
<div id="player"></div>

<script>

    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);


    var player;
    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
            height: '390',
            width: '640',
            videoId: 'u1zgFlCw8Aw',
            playerVars: { 'autoplay': 1, 'controls': 0, 'html5': 1 },

            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });



    }

    function onPlayerReady(event) {

    }

    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {

        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING ) {


        }
    }


</script>
```

Comment: See my edit with <video>

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `event.target.playVideo();` when player is ready.

**HTML**

```
<video id="player"></video>
```

**JS**

```
let tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api";
let firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

let player;
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '390',
        width: '640',
        videoId: 'u1zgFlCw8Aw',
        playerVars: { 'autoplay': 1, 'controls': 0, 'html5': 1 },

        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
}

function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
}

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING ) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the answer provided by martialdidit but unfortunately, it loads the youtube player controls but the video is not played..

A investigation lends me that on mobile, to save bandwith, the autoplay functionality was disabled and forbidden.. found this link for iOS, i'm supposing this is the same for android 
https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/AudioandVideoTagBasics/AudioandVideoTagBasics.html